# How to find a Complete and Independent System of Representatives?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

We have the following equivalence relation:

$$x\,p\,y\iff x-y\in\Bbb C$$

Find a Complete and Independent System of Representatives (CISR). Let $S$ be the CISR.

What I know: $S\subseteq\Bbb C$ and $S$ is:

- Complete: $\forall x \in\Bbb C, x\,p\, X$ for some $X \in S$. (Every element of $\Bbb C$ has a class representative)
- Independent: $Y\, \lnot p\, Z$ if $Y,Z \in S$. (There are no equivalent classes in $S$)

How should I find $S$?

Comment: Is $C$ the field of complex numbers?

Comment: Yes, C is the field of complex numbers.

Comment: HINT: How many equivalence classes does $p$ have?

Comment: I suppose an infinity? For example, 1+i is equivalent to 452 + i so is 634 + i ; But 1 + 2i is equivalent to 625 + 2i and so on.